# How to stop propagation of scroll event in case of a modal view?

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I have this `modal` React component:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import useOnClickOutside from '../../hooks/useOnClickOutside'
import Button from '../codrop/Button'
import styles from './Modal.module.scss'
var Scroll = require('react-scroll')
var scroll = Scroll.animateScroll

interface Props {
    children?: React.ReactNode
    title?: string
    completion?: Function
    [key: string]: any
    isMyFlex?: Boolean
}
const Modal = ({ children, title, completion, isMyFlex, ...rest }: Props) => {
    return (
        <div className="overlay">
            <div className="cnt-box cnt-call2 modal">
                <div className="caption" style={{ paddingRight: 'unset' }}>
                    <div
                        style={{
                            display: 'flex',
                            justifyContent: 'space-between',
                        }}
                    >
                        <h2 style={{ fontSize: '30px', fontWeight: '500' }}>{title}</h2>
                        <span
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                completion?.()
                            }}
                            style={{
                                fontFamily: 'Icons',
                                fontSize: '2rem',
                                cursor: 'pointer',
                            }}
                        >
                            c
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    {children}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Modal
```

And following two style:

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
    width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
    height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
    z-index: 2000; /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.modal {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-width: 470px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 30px 50px;
}
```

When modal / overlay is present, and I scroll in mobil, I see on the bottom, as some pixlel is visilbe from background, that the background i scrolling, though not the foreground.

Is it a way to prevent this scrolling?

I tried to add `overflow: hidden;` to the overlay style, did not help.

---

I tried hide `overflow` when component appears, but has no effect, why?

```
const Modal = ({ children, title, completion, isMyFlex, ...rest }: Props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
        return () => {
            document.body.style.overflow = 'unset'
        }
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, trying to scroll an element that has already reached the bottom will scroll the parent. You can use the `overscroll-behavior` CSS property on the modal to prevent this behavior:

```
overscroll-behavior: contain;
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior for the documentation.

Comment: Did not work, same phenomenon happens :(